# How to add autorefecting in reactQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

Hi I am working with a graphql API and I need to automatically re fetch data after an interval(eg. 3 second). I am using reactQuery and tried some hacks like setInterval but its not working fine.

```
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(['get_trnx_logs', quoteTokenAddress], () => {
  return bitqueryService.getTokenPairTranxLogs(quoteTokenAddress)
})

const feedData = data?.ethereum.dexTrades
? settingTranxLogData(quoteTokenAddress, data.ethereum.dexTrades)
: []
```

Please help me with this, Or is there a way with Ajax to that also?

Comment: Hi, you can refer to this doc, https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery
I think you have to use "refetchInterval" option if you want to do interval fetching

Comment: @WesleyLoh I already tried that but IDK why its not working

Comment: Is the react-query not refetching (You can inspect the dev-tools network tab to observe) or it's, but the data not begin update?

Comment: @WesleyLoh yes the data is not updating

Comment: You can have a look at this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j5jmfk , is there anything you missing?

Comment: @WesleyLoh The main thing is where to put `refetchInterval: 3000` in my code?

Comment: You can pass an object which has a "refetchInterval" property into your useQuery() third argument. Just like the link above

Comment: @WesleyLoh nothing is happening.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a minimum reproduce on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/), so i can help you to find out the problem

Comment: @WesleyLoh you can check here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sk5kv2?file=index.tsx its not working properly but you will get the idea

Answer (score 1):

react-query supports a `refetchInterval` option for that:

```
useQuery(key, fn, { refetchInterval: 5000 })
```

this refetches every 5 seconds.